# Database Design - 1 to 2 relationship

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, database-design

I am designing a database to keep track of games played over time. A game has two players. Currently, I have two tables: players and games.

**Players**
id
name
rating

**Games**
id
redplayer_id
red_score
blueplayer_id
blue_score

I recognize that this is not well normalized, but as its just a 1 to 2 relationship, I'm not sure what would be better. I'm thinking along the lines of adding a players_games table:

**Players_games**
id
match_id
player_id
player_side (red/blue)

Then there would be two players_games for every game.

Does this make sense?

Comment: if its strickted only for 2 players only, why just put 'player1_id' and 'player2_id' ..etc as columns in the matchs table, for small things its better to keep things simple i guess

Comment: Agree. Just because it looks simple, does not mean it is not right. It could be even the best solution

Comment: The Game table doesn't seem to contain entities. You don't show any attributes that would apply to a Game entity, such as Name or Level_of_Difficulty. It defines a relationship between exactly two players, which looks like just what you are asking for.

Comment: I currently have player1 and player 2 in the matches table as you describe. As a specific player can be either player 1 or player 2, it seems cumbersome to query for all of a specific player's matches.

Comment: Formulate the queries needed for each.  It will be a good exercise in learning SQL, and it will probably tell you which way to build the Schema.